# jquery addClass doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

the jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '#fun', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var request = $.ajax({
      url: "example.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {bla: blabla},
      dataType: "html"
    });

    request.done(function(msg) {
        if(msg)
        {
            $this.addClass("btn btn-info btn-small marked");
            $("#isMarked", $this).val(msg)
        }
        else if(!msg)
        {
            $this.addClass("btn btn-small unmarked");
            $("#isMarked", $this).val(msg);
        }
    });
```

and the button

```
<a id='fun' class='btn btn-info btn-small marked' href='#'>fun</a>
```

example.php will return a value either 0 or 1 (indicate true or false)
so the msg will be 0 or 1

the addClass in else if(!msg) can't works. I can't find the problem. any idea?

Comment: i don't meant to be contentious but it's your jquery that doesn't work, not the method call. A bit more fiddling might have highlighted the problem - always a good idea to make sure your code actually does what you think it's doing.

Comment: Thanks. the jquery works well, except the "else if()" like epascarello stated. btw i am cleaning up this jquery to make it better. you may give some idea XD

note: sorry, maybe i didn't state jquery code properly, they actually work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`msg` will be a string so you are comparing a string in the if so it should always be true since a string is a truthy value.

```
​var str1 = "0";
var str2 = "1";

var x = str1 ? "true" : "false";
var y = str2 ? "true" : "false";

​alert(x+"\n"+y);​​​​
```

Comment: Thanks. i tested and this is the problem. I solved it by checking the value --> if(msg == '1')